# Top navigation bar, dropdown overflow problem

Tags: html, css

There is this W3schools example of dropdown in the top navigation bar. In the CSS section of the code, the navbar has property overflow set to hidden. In the HTML section of the code, the dropdown section is a part of the navbar section.
Now as I hover over the dropdown button, the dropdown-content(hidden section) becomes visible(changed the property, display, from none to block) and there is an overflow as the dropdown-content overflows from the navbar section (I even checked using inspect elements the height of the navbar does not change when the dropdown-content is visible).
Now the question is since the overflow property of navbar is hidden, why is the dropdown-content is visible( it is an overflow)? And why the height of navbar not changing (height of navbar is not specified in the styling) and an additional division of significant height got added into it? 
Here is the code from the example:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is because `.navbar` div has its position set to `static`  by default which allows absolutely position child elements not to be clipped. Try setting the `.navbar` position to `relative` and you will notice that the dropdown is now clipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a few things, the `.down-content` class is set to `position: absolute;` which essentially ignores `overflow: hidden;` as well as the height of the navbar and essentially most other things. Also the navbar does not have a specified height so there really isn't anything limiting it's size.

In this example below I removed `position: absolute;` from the `.down-content` class and also added a height of 75px to the `.navbar` class. Check it out

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 75px;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So if there isn't anything limiting the size of the navbar, why doesn't it resize when dropdown-content becomes visible?

Comment: It does, Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/z9bq4dox/  In this example, literally the only thing I did was remove `position: absolute` from the `.dopdown-content` class and I did NOT set a fixed height for the navbar in this example.

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown is not considered overflow here. Overflow occurs when the content of an element is too big to fit its specified area. The nav bar does not have a fixed height - the height is determined by its content (including padding). Therefore the dropdown does not "overflow", as the navbar is "flexible" so to speak.